# how to plot box chart with error lines in gnuplot

Tags: linux, charts, gnuplot

my data set is like this:

```
    5   12.467  12.331865   12.602135   12.8    12.8    12.8
    10  122.766 121.64268   123.88932   51.50933304 48.67632    54.34234696
    15  42.97799961 40.61421    45.34179039 6.254   5.91003 6.59797
    20  70.933  70.379865   71.486135   0   0   0
    25  1226.94033297   1225.463565 1228.41710203   1001.91700041   977.46603459    1026.367965
    30  55.537  52.482465   58.591535   0   0   0
    40  1628.744    1598.99428  1658.49372  0   0   0
```

Column 1 is the xtics and columns 3 and 6 are the main data.
column 2,4 and 5,7 are the error margins. how can I plot this data in box chart?
The following code plot it with lines chart:

```
    plot [0:50] "data.dat" using 1:2:3:4 with yerrorlines title "title1", \
    "" using 1:5:6:7 with yerrorlines title "title2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with

```
set style histogram errorbars gap 1
set boxwidth 0.9
set style fill solid 1.00 border 0
set style data histograms
plot "data.dat" using 2:3:4:xtic(stringcolumn(1)) with histograms title "title1",\
    "" u 5:6:7 w hist t "title2"
```

This is not very pretty but at least should give you what you want as far as I understand:

[image]